# Meteor template helpers in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I can't run *any* sort of computation (reactive or otherwise) inside of a template helper when using coffeescript, only return constant values.

```
if Meteor.isClient
    Template.fg.helpers(
        f: () -> [{val:1},{val:4},{val:9}] # works.
        g: () -> [{val: i*i} for i in [1..10]] # doesn't work.
    )
```

and the template

```
<template name="fg">
  {{#each f}} 
    <div>f: {{val}}</div>
  {{/each}} 
  {{#each g}} 
    <div>g: {{val}}</div>
  {{/each}} 
</template>
```

produces

```
f: 1
f: 4
f: 9
g:
```

But it works fine using javascript. Any suggestion on how to make `g` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [site](http://discontinuously.com/2012/05/iteration-in-coffeescript/#comprehensions_and_binding) could help.

So like this site mentions do something like this:

```
g: () -> (val: i*i for i in [0...10])
```

But I could be wrong, I an not really familiar with coffeescript or meteor.

Comment: Oops, coffeescript list comprehensions use parens not brackets. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your function g and it will work

```
Template.fg.helpers
f: () -> [{val:1},{val:4},{val:9}] # works.


g: () -> 
    for i in [1..10] # this also works
        val: i*i
```

It will give following out put

```
f: 1
f: 4
f: 9
g: 1
g: 4
g: 9
g: 16
g: 25
g: 36
g: 49
g: 64
g: 81
g: 100
```

Hope it will work :)